# client.on("message",function(){}) not being called in whatsapp-web.js

Tags: android, node.js, express, message, whatsapp

I am trying to create a whatsapp bot with whatsapp-web.js library.

When I try to send messages, client.on("message",function(){}) is not being called.

Note: that the client.on("ready",function(){}) works fine and I get a Wall-e alive reply in my whatsapp android application.

```
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const { Client,  MessageMedia } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const client = new Client();

client.on('qr', qr => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
    client.getChats().then(chats => {
        const myGroup = chats.find(id => id.name === "Wall-E")
        client.sendMessage(myGroup.id._serialized, "Walle alive!")
    });
});

client.on('message',async message => {
console.log('messag request')
console.log(message.body)
if (message.body === 'wall-e !ping') {
    console.log('ping request')
    client.sendMessage(message.from, 'pong');
} else if (message.body === 'wall-e ~meme') {
    console.log('meme request')
    const meme = await axios('https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme').then(res => res.data)
    client.sendMessage(message.from, await MessageMedia.formUrl(meme.url))
} else if (message.body === 'wall-e ~joke') {
    console.log('joke request')
    const joke = await axios('https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any?safe-mode').then(res => res.data)
    if(joke.joke){
        await client.sendMessage(message.from, joke.joke)
        }else if(joke.setup){
        const jokeMessage= await client.sendMessage(message.from, joke.setup)
        if(joke.delivery){
            setTimeout(function(){  jokeMessage.reply(joke.delivery)},5000)
        }
    }
});
client.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before this could be because of the older version of WhatsApp-api.js, try uninstalling the whatsapp-api.js package and install it again. it will start working.